# Symfony2 pagination: serializing a form in a hyperlink

Tags: php, forms, symfony, pagination

This should be easy but can't find a solution for this problem. I want to paginate the result of a search query. User will use a form with multiple criteria and them can browser the results page per page.

I do not want to use KnpPaginatorBundle because search can return thousands of result and I don't want to hydrate them all. I use [Doctrine paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) and the pagination part works well if the search criteria are hardcoded.

My problem is that the *next page* button is an hyperlink that pass the correct *page* GET variable, and I I'm struggling with passing the search criteria in the link.

The form is working well when submitted, all the criteria are passed via GET or POST depending on my configuration and the form data is updated when I call `$form->handleRequest()`. I would like to be able to use the same GET variable on my *next page* hyperlink so that `handleRequest` will allow me to get the search criteria, and so that the search form, that is displayed on each page, is displayed correctly.

**How can I generate the url encoded string to add to the *next page* hyperlink ? I'm also opened to a better solution to keep the search criteria between each page, but cannot saved them in session.**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can you not save the search criteria in the session?

Comment: There are two main raisons: the first is that we need that the search works simultaneously in different tabs of the browser (it can be overcome by some kind of _search key_ that will be different accross tabs, but it sounds more like a hack to me). For this first reason we try to avoid session as much as possible. Second, is that we need the link being shareable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the Symfony Router to generate your previous and next pages urls. So you just have to give its your search criteria as additionnal parameters. As those criteria aren't route parameters, Symfony will place them in the GET parameters.

```
$this->get('router')->generate('search_page', $criteria, true);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls

Comment: I did not knew that, very handful! As my form has entity fields, I should have some code to convert the form data (that will contain an entity) to something more adequate to the router (with ids). I hoped there would exist the 'reverse' function of `$form->handleRequest()` but apparently not.

Comment: Do you mean `$form->getData()` which return your form data as an array ?

Comment: Yes that's what I though to do: first `$data = $form->getData()`. As my form has something like `'$builder->add('product','entity',array('class'=>'MyBundle:Product','property'=>'name'));`, `$data` will contain an associative array with entities as value. I would then loop on this array to replace the entities by their Id and pass the resulting array to the Router. Is there a simpler way ?

Comment: It's the only way I can see :)